# File upload control not accepting .xls files in some browsers?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I am validating file types after uploading the files to file upload control. In validation I am allowing .xls file types. But in some browsers are not allowing the .xls files.

What could be the problem?

```
var fileExt = ["application/pdf","application/msword", "image/gif", "image/jpeg", 
               "image/png", "text/csv", "text/html", "application/vnd.ms-excel", 
               "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
               "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-
                       officedocument.presentationml.presentation", 
               "application/vnd.openxmlformats-
                       officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "text/plain"];
if (fileExt.indexOf(file.type) <= -1) {
    $('input[id="Attachment"]').removeClass("valid").addClass("input-validation-error");
    $('#spanAttachment').removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("input-validation-error red");
    $('#spanAttachment').empty();
    $('#spanAttachment').append("<span for='FirstName' 
                            class=''>Filetype is not accepted.</span>");
    $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

http://i.stack.imgur.om/CVQfL.png

Comment: In this case, I am assuming some browsers are not parsing the file type correctly, and simply sending the default file type instead of `application/vnd.ms-speadsheet` type.  Alert `file.type` in the offending browsers to see what it is actually returning.

Comment: @tommy, alert shows nothing. nothing in alert.

Comment: That would mean those browsers are not returning a file type at all, which would explain why it is not passing your test or file.type does not do what you are expecting.  Any reason to not use the extension of the file as opposed to the MIME type?

Answer (score 0):

use also those MIME-TYPES:

```
application/excel
application/x-excel
application/x-msexcel
```